# How to detect changes in Hyperon persistance engine?

Tags: java, hyperon

I use Hyperon 1.5.54 and persist my model with Hyperon peristance engine.

Is there an option to check from the level of Property object if entity was modified? If so – is there any marker in entity to show which ones has been modified?

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

**revision** field on bundle can be compared – every persist() results in incrementing revision by one.

If you want to check which entities has been modified, you need to make a **diff** before saving.

diff() returns the list of "dirty" entities (also new and deleted).
and on those dirty entities you can run visitor, or just iterate thru them:

For example:

```
BundleDiff diff = bundleService.diff ( bundle );

diff.getEntitiesToInsert()  // detected new entities
diff.getEntitiesToUpdate()  // dirty entities

// this code set lastupdate to every dirty entity
for ( EntityDiff d in diff.getEntitiesToUpdate() ) {
    entityId = d.getId()
    Property prop = bundle.find( entityId ) // get entity by id

    // set last udpate if entity has such field
    if (p.getType().getCompoundType().getProp("lastUpdate") != null) { 
        p.set("lastupdate", new Date())
    }
}
```